# Why is PDO converting my bool(false) param to string('')?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I have a problem with a new MariaDB 10.5.8 install.  `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is set, and when I try to use `$sql` of:

```
'INSERT INTO test (flag) VALUES (?)'
```

(where `flag` is defined as `tinyint(1)`) with `var_dump($params)` showing as:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I get this message:

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column `mydb`.`test`.`flag` at row 1
```

If, instead, I do:

```
'INSERT INTO test (flag) VALUES (false)'
```

with no parameters, it works as expected.

This is how I connect to the database:

```
$this->PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8mb4', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES  => false,
]);

$this->PDO->query("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");
```

and this is how I send the query/params to MariaDB:

```
$stmt = self::$_instance->PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

If I try to insert `true` instead of `false`, everything works fine.  `true` is being converted to `1` somewhere along the lines, and `false` to `''`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> All values are treated as **PDO::PARAM_STR**.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

The `execute()` method does not enable you to specify the variable's type. It always casts to a string, which is why you're getting strange results:

```
php > var_dump((string) true);
string(1) "1"

php > var_dump((string) false);
string(0) ""
```

You can use [PDOStatement::bindValue()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to specify the value's type:

```
$statement->bindValue('some_bool', true, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Note that MySQL lacks a 'true' boolean type, which is why I'd recommend `PDO::PARAM_INT` over `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I've been using PDO for years but on a MySQL installation that had `sql_mode=''` (I didn't document doing this, and don't recall my reasons why). A new install with default `sql_mode` threw up this problem.  Previously I assumed everything was being sent as the intended type, because that's what I thought I was doing and it APPEARED to be working...

I assume there's no PDO option/constant to change this behaviour (similar to how I set `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES  => false` for fetching non-string data)?

Comment: @Codemonkey To my knowledge, no, there indeed isn't. If you're writing / running a lot of database queries, you might want to look towards an ORM library (Doctrine, Eloquent, etc) that does most of the heavy lifting in mapping variable types to proper SQL rows / types.  But for simple applications, calling `bindValue()` in a `foreach` loop will probably be Good Enough.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, to my knowledge `PDO::PARAM_BOOL` and `PDO::PARAM_INT` are the same when using PDO_MySQL.

Comment: This does not seem to work in PHP 8+. It complains «out of range value for column» even if `bindValue("some_bool", true, PDO::PARAM_INT)` is passed.

Answer (score 7):

A much simpler solution would be just to cast a boolean value to int beforehand

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO test (flag) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->execute([(int)$flag]);
```

Comment: True, MySQL doesn't particularly care that you're inserting numeric strings instead of integers. But other Databases might. Also note that casting basically ignores any error handling, since `(int) 'whatever' === 0`.

Comment: I'd already done something similar in my DB wrapper function as soon as I discovered the "problem", as a stop-gap while I figured out what was going on.  Just loops through all the params and converts them to 1 or 0 if they're === true or false.

Comment: @Duroth As far as I know your approach also casts to an integer but only once. YCS approach casts to an integer then to a string and then back to an integer, correct?

Comment: @Dharman No; this approach will cast to an integer, then to a string. That's all. The statement will then be executed with a string parameter. Which _could potentially_ cause errors, although it most likely won't, at least for MySQL connections. My approach should be slightly more reliable. Although there is a lot of conjecture here.

Comment: @Duroth i think it's about the the full chain of conversions, PHP casts to int, then PDO casts to string and finally mysql converts to int

Comment: @Duroth there is a problem, as soon as you are introducing some automation to your code, it makes your approach extremely hard to use.

Comment: @Duroth In my opinion both ways are identical in terms of the outcome. The main point is that booleans must be cast to an integer because MySQL doesn't have a native boolean data type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick snippet that would solve booleans casting to empty string in pdo params

```php
$params = array_map(fn($param) => is_bool($param) ? intval($param) : $param, $params);
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know this theoretically could cause an issue but this is the behaviour I desire when working with booleans parameters. Ideally `$statement->execute($params)` would infer the types instead of treating all parameters as `PDO::PARAM_STR` (or have a mechanism to do this easily).

That being said I don't see how the example query you said applies `DELETE FROM users WHERE email='0'` would not cause any issues I can imagine unless you have a  `0` in your email column

Comment: Man, you are correct. I confused your automation with another case.